# Add .lib to solution and link to it in Visual Studio 2013 (libconfig)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2013, libconfig

**I am trying to add [libconfig](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/) (a .lib) to my VS13 solution.** I downloaded the tar ball, extract, and build the project. The [manual](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/libconfig_manual.html#Using-the-Library-from-a-C_002b_002b-Program) states:

> to link with the library, specify `-lconfig++' as an argument to the
>   linker.

---

From [Linking dll in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7845886/363829), I understand that I need to link directory to the .lib file. So I create a folder, "Libraries" and copy the .dll and .lib to it. I then set that folder as a Library Directory:

[image]

I understand that by right clicking the project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input, I set libconfig++.lib as an additional dependencies.

[image]

The provided libconfig example1 uses the following premable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <libconfig.h++>
using namespace libconfig;
```

But when I try to replicate this, I get an error
[image]

```
 fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libconfig.h++': No such file or directory
```

---

If I remove `#include <libconfig.h++>` and `using namespace libconfig;` it will build. So what am I missing / doing wrong?

Comment: @HansPassant I changed to `#include "libconfig.h++"` but still getting `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libconfig.h++': No such file or directory`

Comment: Where *is* that file?  Where did you copy it to?  Add the directory that contains it to the Include Directories setting.

Comment: As Hans says: get your include directories right so that the #include compiles. That is non-optional. The using namespace libconfig; is optional.