# MSVC Unresolved Eternal Symbols in DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, msvc12

Can someone help me understand why MSVC 12 2013 reports these symbols are unresolved?

```
Error   239 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static double const Wm3::Math<double>::DEG_TO_RAD" (?DEG_TO_RAD@?$Math@N@Wm3@@2NB) referenced in function "protected: void __cdecl Matt::ExternalNavConverter::CExternalNavConverter::DoProcessExternalNav(void)" (? DoProcessExternalNav@CExternalNavConverter@ExternalNavConverter@Matt@@IEAAXXZ)  C:\Users\mrussell\workspace\Matt\build-conan-Release\Libraries\MattClient\ExternalNavConverter.lib(ExternalNavConverter.obj)    MattClient
```

The symbol `DEG_TO_RAD` is defined in my `Wml.dll` file, which I'm quite sure is in my `%PATH%` when I start MSVC.

The output from `dumpbin` for the DLL is:

```
dumpbin /exports C:\Users\mrussell\.conan\data\wml\3.x\ntc\stable\package\a4501f33ae09df332b76b4d6f0e5cebffbe83874\bin\Wml3.dll  | grep -i DEG_TO_RAD
 143   8E 00031A64 ?DEG_TO_RAD@?$Math@M@Wm3@@2MB
 144   8F 00031A98 ?DEG_TO_RAD@?$Math@N@Wm3@@2NB
```

And for the LIB:

```
dumpbin /exports  C:\Users\mrussell\.conan\data\wml\3.x\ntc\stable\package\a4501f33ae09df332b76b4d6f0e5cebffbe83874\lib\Wml3.lib | grep DEG_TO_RAD
  ?DEG_TO_RAD@?$Math@M@Wm3@@2MB (public: static float  const Wm3::Math<float>::DEG_TO_RAD)
  ?DEG_TO_RAD@?$Math@N@Wm3@@2NB (public: static double const Wm3::Math<double>::DEG_TO_RAD)
```

I set up a [minimal example showing the failed linking here](https://gist.github.com/kheaactua/bcee42148faa063655c5042102938a1f), unfortunately I'm not sure I can put the headers or `.lib` file.

I'm not that familiar with `dumpbin`, I'm more accustomed to `nm` with `c++filt`..  But to me, this suggests that the symbol `DEG_TO_RAD` is exported in the DLL.

In the Linker command line window, I can see that by bin path (path the to DLL) is provided as a `/LIBPATH`, and the full path to the `.lib` is provided as well (provided in "*Additional Dependencies*".)

Could this be because I might be mixing up shared and static libs together?  Or a sign that despite me thinking the DLL is in my path, somehow it isn't?  Or the symbols in the DLL aren't actually there? (the equivalent of a non-`T` for the symbol type in `nm`)

I'm going through the list given [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12573818/1861346), but so far am just confused as to why it is not working.

Comment: This is a linker error, you need to link with `Wml.lib` (the export library for Wml.dll).  At the linking stage the linker has no interest in `Wml.dll`.

Comment: In addition to what Richard says, the Visual Studio project options have a linker settings section where you can specify "additional dependencies". This where you put the name of the LIB file corresponding to that DLL.

Comment: hey @Richard Critten , yeah, I am linking with `Wml.lib`, and as I said above, `Wml.lib` is specified in my `Additional Dependencies`.  I was under the impression though that `.lib`s for shared libraries usually only declared the symbols that are actually defined in the `dll`, so doesn't the DLL have to be find'able in the PATH?

In anycase though, yeah, the 'lib' is specified.  That's why I'm so confused.

Comment: Yes the DLL needs to be find-able at __runtime__.  However `LNK2019` is a link time error.

Comment: Alright, so I still have no idea why it won't link then.  The symbols are in the lib, the `.lib` is specified as a link target, the symbols in the error match the symbols in `dumpbin`. :(

Comment: Well, the .`lib` already in the *Additional Dependencies*, and if the `DLL` isn't required at all during linktime, then moving the DLL shouldn't make any difference?  I can give the `#pragma` recommendation a go though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking dll in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845886/linking-dll-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I still really don't think it's a duplicate, as as the question states, the lib is an *Additional Dependency*, but it's still throwing a linking error.

Comment: Did you try this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx

Comment: A [mcve] would be very helpful.

Comment: Is the .lib file in the same folder as the .dll?  Do you get any other errors or messages from the linker?

Comment: Hi @RobertAndrzejuk, I posted a [minimal working example here](https://gist.github.com/kheaactua/bcee42148faa063655c5042102938a1f), you won't be able to build it without the WML source though, I'm awaiting approval to see if I can upload it. (we've tweaked out version of WML, so you can't just download it from the original site.)

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm No, right now I have it laid out such that the `.lib` is in `<base>/lib`, and the `.dll` is in `<base>/bin`.  My error it self is a linker error (`LNK2019`), doesn't that mean it's from the linker?  I'm more familiar with g++ where you can see from the output whether the error derives from the compiler or linker, I'm not sure how to see that difference with MSVC.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Hey, the original project (not the minimal working example) relies on tonnes of DLLs.  Normally they're easy to link against, it's simply this one DLL that I have trouble with.  I suppose my ultimate question is that, given the output from `dumpbin`, and that the lib is specified as an `Additional Dependency`, why can't it link?  What could be special about this lib that blocks it?  Given the `dumpbin` output, is there even room for something to go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that while the WML symbols were exported properly with `__declspec(dllexport)`, they weren't being imported properly by my app.

In the [minimal working example](https://gist.github.com/kheaactua/bcee42148faa063655c5042102938a1f) I added a snippit of `Wm3Platforms.h` where `dllexport` and `dllimport` are declared.  Typically (in my experience) at least, these are controlled by a single preprocessor definition (if on, do `dll_export`, if off, do `dll_import`), but this code demands `WM3_DLL_IMPORT` is declared to make it importable.

Declaring `WM3_DLL_IMPORT` fixed my issue.

So, turns out my issue was specific to this lib's source code....