# static library for libssh causes unresolved symbols in vc10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, libssh

I have a C++ dll project in visual studio 10 that I am trying to use libssh for.  I would like to statically link the libssh functionality.  When I use the non-static libary and include the dll during runtime, the code compiles and executes as expected.  But if I change to the static library then I cannot compile and get linker errors for the libssh functions I am trying to use e.g.:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ssh_free referenced in function ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you by chance forget to set `LIBSSH_STATIC`?  [This page](http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_linking.html) says you have to define it yourself in the compiler options.

Comment: im using the ssh.lib binary in the folder named "static" that came from the libssh website.  The file is much larger than the shared lib but I guess Im assuming they compiled it correctly.  Does vs10 have a tool like nm to look at symbols in the lib?

Comment: If you read the page I linked, it looks like you have to define that symbol yourself in the compiler options.  The VS project properties should have a section for your own defines (`/D` I think).

Comment: I did read the page but I assumed they were talking about building libssh, not linking with libssh.  I will try your suggestion and post back.

Comment: this question provides more proof for your answer and also has an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704374/linking-error-lnk2019-in-msvc-unresolved-symbols-with-imp-prefix-but-shoul

Comment: well that resolved the unresolved symbols for that libssh functions I'm calling directly, but now I have 30 new unresolved symbols coming from ssh.lib.  I wonder if that library needs another library?    ssh.lib(misc.c.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAStringToAddressA@20 referenced in function _ssh_is_ipaddr_v4

Comment: added w2_32.lib which resolved that one but now I have 69 more unresolved symbols.  e.g. ssh.lib(keyfiles.c.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _RSA_free referenced in function _privatekey_from_file

Comment: I'm thinking these are openssl symbols.  Probably need to track down/build a static openssl library

Comment: Before you chase down every missing library, you might want to see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8204677/46821).

Comment: added static versions of libeay32.lib and ssleay32.lib and I'm down to 7 unresolved symbols.  However these don't look good.  e.g. LIBCMT.lib(tidtable.obj) : error LNK2005: __encoded_null already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)

Comment: I read that but if I understand correctly, it's telling you how to build a static openssl lib.  I've got those already.

Comment: building with /MDd temporarily resolves the "already defined" errors.  This is probably bc I've got mixed debug/release libraries.  Static zlib is next.

Comment: ok, all compiled.  if it works, i'll go back and compile all these static libs myself to get rid of the "already defined" business

Comment: Nice!  Glad you could figure it out.