# Troubles liking libraries on a Win32 dll for VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, dynamic-linking, kinect-sdk, point-cloud-library

I am having problems to link my libraries in order to make a dll on VS2013. I have to say that I needed a Desktop dll because of some troubles with the winapifamily so this is a Win32 project and I guess that migh also be an issue but I have not better solution so far. Some of the errors I get:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_NuiCreateSensorByIndex
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_NuiSetDeviceStatusCallback
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_NuiGetSensorCount
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl pcl::console::print(enum pcl::console::VERBOSITY_LEVEL,char const *,...)" (?print@console@pcl@@YAXW4VERBOSITY_LEVEL@12@PEBDZZ)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: bool __cdecl pcl::PCLBase<struct pcl::PointXYZ>::deinitCompute(void)" (?deinitCompute@?$PCLBase@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@pcl@@IEAA_NXZ)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: bool __cdecl pcl::PCLBase<struct pcl::PointXYZ>::initCompute(void)" (?initCompute@?$PCLBase@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@pcl@@IEAA_NXZ)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include external resources you need to explicitly [feed them into the Linker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822.aspx) or reference them as dynamic lib ([explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/784bt7z7.aspx) or [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14wsce5.aspx))

This answer shows a few good steps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20410798/351861

Comment: Yes, you were right. I had some libs not included, thank you!