# How to use a dll-file in Visual Studio C++ when it didn't come with a lib-file and header files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, openh264

I want to use the [OpenH264 library](https://github.com/cisco/openh264) in my Visual Studio C++ project.
Now, I was given the advice to use the precompiled version, since they already offer that.

But when I look at the [releases](https://github.com/cisco/openh264/releases) there only is a precompiled dll-file, nothing else. Or I'm just incapable of finding the rest.

Anyways, now I have to use the dll-file without any lib- and header files which [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495795/how-do-i-use-a-third-party-dll-file-in-visual-studio-c) shouldn't be necessary. So what gives?

What would be the recommended way of advancing from this point on? Can I create the missing files myself or is there a better way of progressing?

Comment: Just taken a quick look but no prioir knowledge: Download the DLL and the source. In the source there seems to be a def file (openh264.def) and a header (codec_api.h). Its probable that is all you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate an import library (LIB-file) from a DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946322/how-to-generate-an-import-library-lib-file-from-a-dll)