# How to set the path to DLLs in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I have developed a C++ application that relies on external library dependencies, primarily SDL.
Would like to store the library and DLL files together in a different folders than the `.vcxproj` file.

**Question 1:** How to make Visual Studio "find" those DLLs in the folders?

**Question 2:** When building I want to store in the same folder structure, how is that achievable/is it achievable?

**Example:**

`Project_folder/SDL/SDL_2/lib/x86` -> here are the SDL 2 DLLs.

`Project_folder/SDL/SDL2_image/lib/x86` -> more DLLs.

**Notice** that there are two different folders that I need Visual Studio to "get" the DLLs.

**What I have tried:**

**About Question 1:** [How do I set the path to a DLL file in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119539/how-do-i-set-the-path-to-a-dll-file-in-visual-studio)
That does not appear to work for me or at least I could not make it work for me. It does however do the job if I store all the DLLs in the specified folder.

**About Question 2:** [Documentation about post-build events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/cpp/add-references-managed#using-post-build-events) This seems to do part of the job. I can now copy the DLLs to a different folder, but the application won't be able to load them as they need to live where the executable is.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click your project and click Add>Com Referance
2. Click "Browse" button and choose dll

Comment: No such thing as a "Com Reference" under the "Add" sub-menu.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for Question 1:**

To include DLL files from a folder or a multiple folders you can use the following, specified in the `properties` of your project.

> To add the following specifications on where to look for DLLs:
>
> `Right click your project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Environment ->`
>
> For one path use:
>
> `PATH=$(ProjectDir)\SDL\SDL_2\lib\x86;%PATH%`
>
> For multiple specify with `;` in your Example:
> `PATH=$(ProjectDir)\SDL\SDL_2\lib\x86;$(ProjectDir)\SDL\SDL2_image\lib\x86;%PATH%`

Note:

`$(ProjectDir)` <- Specifies the root directory of your project

`PATH=` <- Specifies Absolute path to the root directory of your project.
Must be used otherwise it won't look in the specified path.

`%PATH%` <- Modifies or Appends the current Reference without overwriting the core of it.

**Answer to Question 2:**

For this you should add them directly to the .exe location, there are ways around it but it is way too over-complicated and should not be done neither way.

How I generally copy all required DLLs into my targetDirectory is to:

Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Build Events -> Pre-Link Events

Using the following command

`copy "$(ProjectDir)DLLs\*.dll" "$(TargetDir)" ping -n 6 127.0.0.1 > nul`

The following takes all the .dll endings and adds them to the TargetDir.

ping is used to delay it so that they are linked correctly as the " Copy " would run, but continue with the rest and linking in that instance would be done incorrectly.

To load them from a different folder it should be done by inside the code itself.

Some references used or good to read about:

1. [3rd Party DLLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495795/how-do-i-use-a-third-party-dll-file-in-visual-studio-c)
2. [Loading DLLs](https://tbhaxor.com/loading-dlls-using-cpp-in-windows/)
3. [Link an executable to DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/linking-an-executable-to-a-dll?view=msvc-170)